Legacy device cannot access Samba share anymore after switch from 16.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS
I had a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine using Samba out of the box with something like this defined (and a few more shares, but unimportant here):
[audio-anon]
    comment = FLAC (anonymous)
    path = /nas/nas/audio/flac
    browseable = no
    valid users = ftp

and no other changes to smb.conf. All fine for years.
I recently reinstalled another machine with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and made the very same change to smb.conf. Everything works fine when connecting through some Windows machine or smbclient on another Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.
Unfortunately, a legacy device I have zero control on and minimal information about cannot access the share anymore.
After a bit of search, inspection of the logs, etc., I realized it might be using some older protocol and therefore I added all this to smb.conf in [global]:
   server min protocol = NT1
   lanman auth = yes
   ntlm auth = yes
   raw NTLMv2 auth = no
   client NTLMv2 auth = no
   map to guest = Bad Password
   security = user

I do not understand every part of it, but it seems to "downgrade" the Samba server to some old behaviour. Alas, while situation has clearly improved (it manages to auth, etc.), it then fails at this point of the level-5 log (there is more later, but this seems the gist of the problem to me):
[2024/09/30 23:37:15.769356,  3] source3/smbd/smb1_process.c:1112(switch_message)
  switch message SMBtrans2 (pid 9725) conn 0x5e05509ec960
[2024/09/30 23:37:15.769361,  5] source3/smbd/uid.c:327(change_to_user_impersonate)
  change_to_user_impersonate: Skipping user change - already user
[2024/09/30 23:37:15.769370,  5] source3/smbd/uid.c:294(print_impersonation_info)
  print_impersonation_info: Impersonated user: uid=(122,122), gid=(0,128), cwd=[/nas/nas/audio/flac]
[2024/09/30 23:37:15.769378,  3] source3/smbd/smb1_trans2.c:2645(call_trans2qpathinfo)
  call_trans2qpathinfo: TRANSACT2_QPATHINFO: level = 512
[2024/09/30 23:37:15.769383,  3] source3/smbd/error.c:78(error_packet_set)
  NT error packet at source3/smbd/smb1_trans2.c(2653) cmd=50 (SMBtrans2) NT_STATUS_INVALID_LEVEL
[2024/09/30 23:37:15.769397,  5] source3/lib/util.c:150(show_msg)
  size=35
  smb_com=0x32
  smb_rcls=72
  smb_reh=1
  smb_err=49152
  smb_flg=128
  smb_flg2=49155
  smb_tid=60757
  smb_pid=242
  smb_uid=49094
  smb_mid=291
  smt_wct=0
  smb_bcc=0

I suspect that NT_STATUS_INVALID_LEVEL is still the result of some legacy protocol issue that is disallowed in the current version of Samba (2:4.19.5+dfsg-4ubuntu9). But truly I have no clue.
Any idea? Is there a way to completely make the newer Samba server behave like the 16.04 LTS one?

I tried a number of things to debug the problem but to no avail. The only solution I found has been to create a Docker container running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and configure it to run Samba. I disabled the Samba service on the host and I packaged Docker running that container into a systemd service, so that I can cleanly use it very much like Samba running on the host (restart at boot, etc.). It works perfectly well and, from some superficial testing, it does not seem to be any significantly slower than Samba running directly in the host OS.
Yet, if anyone has hints on how to address the original problem, I would be much interested.

I had a very similar problem with an old Sonos player. I found the following suggestion on the Sonos user forum, and it works for me.
Add the following additional line to the [global] section of your smb.conf:
smb1 unix extensions = no


Thanks. This one never came up when I was doing my tests, so it is promising. I will try to test this, but I need a little time because I must test it with care not to compromise what now works fine.
